# Vi - Use search command with yank

Tags: linux, unix, vim, vi

I'm trying to use the yank command like this:

```
:0,/string,yy
```

To yank starting from the beginning of the current line, until the first instance of the word "string".

Obviously the above command does not work, as it tries to look for "string,yy". Can someone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: `:0` is beginning of the file, not the beginning of the current line. Which one were you after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a range and the `:yank` ex command to do so

```
:.,/string/yank
```

This can be shortened more to `:,/string/y` as the current line `.` can be assumed and `:y` is short for `:yank`.

Ex commands work line-wise. If you are trying to do this in normal mode and wish to yank characterwise then you are after the following:

```
y/string<cr>
```

For more help see:

```
:h :y
:h :range
```

Comment: Quick question, what does <cr> represent?

Comment: `<cr>` is carriage return. Aka the return key